# Python: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '*'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python script (parser.py) which imports crc32c like this:

```
import crc32c

// ... rest of the code
```

I have installed **crc32c** with the command:

```
arch -arm64  brew install crc32c
```

crc32c was installed here:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/crc32c/1.1.1
```

When executing parser.py file like this:

```
python3.9 parser.py
```

Getting this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crc32c'
```

**What is the way to show to the parser.py file, that crc32c is installed into particular directory?**

I have tried doing like this:

```
sys.path.append('/opt/homebrew/Cellar/crc32c')
```

As well looked into similar question, but can not found solution for my problem.

Comment: Sounds like you are not using the same environment where the package is installed.

Comment: Are you sure the `crc32c` package you installed using brew is actually a Python module?

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim how I could check is it the same environment?

Comment: @gmdev After your question I am not sure, that crc32c is Python module? It contains file like *.a and *.dylib.

Comment: try installing with `python3.9 -m pip install crc32c` I'm not sure you installed a python lib at all

https://pypi.org/project/crc32c/

Comment: Could you use the `zlib.crc32()` function from the built-in [zlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html?highlight=crc#zlib.crc32) module?

Comment: Most of the other comments here are all ways to deal with having an environment issue. First check if you are using something like `venv` or something like that. Then where ever you are running your script, before running it do `pip list` to make sure the module is installed in that environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like that isn't a python package:

https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/crc32c

https://github.com/google/crc32c

There are python checksums available, for instance:
https://pypi.org/project/crc32c/ `python3.9 -m pip install crc32c`
and `zlib.crc32()`

That look like they may suit your needs

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sys.path.append('/opt/homebrew/Cellar/')
```

or, if the package is inside `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/crc32c/1.1.1` (this folder contains a package (=another folder) called `crc32c`)

```
sys.path.append('/opt/homebrew/Cellar/crc32/1.1.1/')
```

before importing the module.

you can try to debug this by calling `help('modules')` in your code after the `sys.path.append` has been called